# My suffix cannot be a man, My whole can ruin your plan

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> My prefix needs me and you.
>
> My suffix cannot be a man.
>
> My infix needs some food.
>
> My whole can ruin your plan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must be

> **weather**.

My prefix needs me and you.

> **we**ather

My suffix cannot be a man.

> weat**her**

My infix needs some food.

> w**eat**her

My whole can ruin your plan.

> "There's no such thing as bad weather, only inappropriate clothing." *--someone whose plans didn't include sun-tanning.*
>
>  *(Also, rain, wind, snow, temperature, ect. can ruin many different plans that take place outside.)*